# Android: error parsing XML, IOException: read failed: EBADF

Tags: xml, parsing, inputstream

When I try to parse the InputStream into the Document I'm getting this error:

java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

The code:

```
private String readLanguageXML(InputStream file)
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try
    {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document dom = builder.parse(file); // ERROR HERE
        file.close();

        Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();

        NodeList items = root.getChildNodes();

        for (int j=0; j<items.getLength(); j++)
        {
            try
            {
                Node dato = items.item(j);
                String etiqueta = dato.getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue();

                languageMap.put(etiqueta, dato.getTextContent());                  
            }
            catch(NullPointerException npe)
            {
                npe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: The problem is with your InputStream so you need to show how that's created.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the InputStream, I was closing it before calling this method